# How to take the mapping fields in Automapper?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I am using Automapper. In that, I create an automapper profile like below:

```
  public MappingProfile()
  {
      CreateMap<Users, UserDetails>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.IsUser, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.RoleId == 1))
            .ForMember(o => o.UserId, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.Id))
            .ReverseMap();
  }
```

***Users***

```
public class Users
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int RoleId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

***UserDetails***

```
public class UserDetails
{
   public int UserId { get;set; }
   public bool IsUser { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In model class `User.cs`, I need to take the mappings fields. i.e) `UserId` in `UserDetails` map from `Id` in `Users` class. How to take like this in automapper? (Or) Is there any other way to take this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - I need to retrieve the fields which are mapped.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this:

In model class `User.cs`,

```
  private readonly IMapper mapper;


   var mappingFields = mapper.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(Users), typeof(UserDetails));
   var propertyMapList = mappingFields.PropertyMaps.ToList();

   foreach (var item in propertyMapList)
   {
       ----------------
       var mappingField = item.SourceMember.Name;  ---> Here, we get the source field name. i.e) Id
   }
```

This is working for me.